# How to get result from `new Func<T>() { ... }?`

Tags: c#, .net

Why do these print different things?

Let's say I have such class:

```
public class ExampleOfFunc
{
    public int Addition(Func<int> additionImplementor)
    {
        if (additionImplementor != null)
            return additionImplementor();
        return default(int);
    }
}
```

And in the `Main` method:

This prints `200`:

```
ExampleOfFunc exampleOfFunc = new ExampleOfFunc();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", exampleOfFunc.Addition(
     () =>
     {
         return 100 + 100;
     }));  // Prints 200
```

But this prints `Prints System.Func'1[System.Int32]`:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", new Func<int>(
    () =>
    {
        return 100 + 100;
    }));  // Prints System.Func`1[System.Int32]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
return additionImplementor();
```

Calls the function and returns its result which is then passed to `Console.WriteLine()`.

While this line

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", new Func<int>(
    () =>
    {
        return 100 + 100;
    }
));
```

merely passes the function to `Console.WriteLine()` without calling it. Add `()` to execute the function before printing it out...

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", new Func<int>(
    () =>
    {
        return 100 + 100;
    }
)());
```

[**Fiddle**](http://dotnetfiddle.net/55Gbvd)

Answer (score 4):

In the second example you only supply the anonymous function as a parameter to Console.WriteLine. You don't actually call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine there are fifty classes and functions such as `ExampleOfFunc.Addition`. How would compiler know which function you had in mind? You have to tell it explicitly.